# Opcache used memory doesn't change

Tags: php, opcache

Below numbers are static. They don't change. I am running magento 2 with PHP 7.3. Is opcache working?

```
Opcode Caching => Up and Running
Optimization => Enabled
SHM Cache => Enabled
File Cache => Disabled
Startup => OK
Shared memory model => mmap
Cache hits => 0
Cache misses => 0
Used memory => 19916856
Free memory => 248518600
Wasted memory => 0
Interned Strings Used memory => 382048
Interned Strings Free memory => 12200440
Cached scripts => 0
Cached keys => 0
Max keys => 65407
OOM restarts => 0
Hash keys restarts => 0
Manual restarts => 0
```